# Find all $A\in \mathcal{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $Ax=x+y$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

I was asked this question yesterday on my linear algebra qualifying exam (to the best of recollection):

**Question 1**: Find all $A\in \mathcal{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ there exists a $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying
\begin{equation}
Ax=x+y. 
\end{equation}

The textbook we used was Golan's *The Linear Algebra a Beginning Graduate Ought to Know*, 3rd edition. In that book I found a similar exercise, p.145, #439, which states:

**Question 2**: Let $A = [a_{ij}] \in \mathcal{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ satisfy the condition that for each $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ there exists
a vector $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ all entries in which are nonnegative satisfying $Av = v+y$. Show that $A = I$.

I did the question last and was rushed, but my work was something to the effect of:

Write $Ax=x+y$ as 
$$
(A-I)x=y.
$$
Then,

1) Any matrix with eigenvalue $\lambda=1$, which has algebraic multiplicity equal to geometric multiplicity equal to $\dim(\mathbb{R}^n)=n$, and

2) A=I.

I retrospectively realize that (I think) these are equivalent.

With the relaxed hypothesis (i.e. no "nonnegative"), could you please help me with a solution to **Question 1**? Thank you in advance!

Comment: For the first question, as stated, $A$ can be any matrix. For any $x$ there exists $y$ such that $Ax=x+y.$ Just take $y=Ax-x.$ For the second question note that $A(-v)=-v+(-y).$ If the coordinates of $y$ and $-y$ are nonnegative then $y=0.$

Answer (score 0):

I believe that $A=I$ is the only matrix for which we can find such a y.  As you have shown we know that $(A-I)x=y$.  On the other hand we must have $A(2x)=2x+y$ which we can solve to $2(A-I)x=y$.  This implies that $y=2y$ so $y$ must be the zero vector and $A$ must be the identity.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $(A-I)x=y$. If $y$ has at least one positive entry, then replacing $x$ with $-x$ violates the restriction for $y$. Thus, $y=0$. Since this must be true for **all** $x$, We must have $A-I=0$, so the claim follows.